# Kotlin override "static" property is subclass

Tags: kotlin

I have an interface(it could be a class, doesn't matter) `Record` which has a field that is accessible like `Record.size`, without having an instance.
As kotlin replaced static with companion objects, I have something like this:

```
interface Record {
    companion object{
        val size = 0
    }
}
```

Now the real problem is when I want to have classes inheriting `Record`: `RecordA` and `RecordB`, which have some other value of `size`, and I want it to be accessible as `Record.size` as well.

It is such a trivial use case that I must be missing something simple. If it can't be done the way i described, what would be the workaround or a more proper solution to this problem?

EDIT: I am now realising that this might simply not be possible. If that's correct, how would you solve this usecase?

Comment: `Record.size` means: the size defined in the companion object of the class Record. It can't possibly look elsewhere than there. If you want to "override" the size, then you need a reference to another object than Record.Companion. If you descibed what you actually want to achieve, at a higher level, then maybe we could help more.

Comment: Moreso overriding a static property is impossible in the JVM since all static functions and variables can't be replaced by a subclass at runtime. At most you will be shadowing the variable, but that would still require specialized code for each unique usage.